# Thymeleaf - get dynamic content on tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, tooltip, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and I have a task to add a tooltip with dynamic content.
If I use the `title` or `data-original-title` attribute, I can insert an HTML tag into the tooltip, but the variable value didn't render. If I use the `th:title` attribute, I can get the desired variable value, but it isn't an HTML tag.

Any advice?

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<div class='row' style='color: white; background-color: black; border-radius: 10px'>
    <div class='col-sm-6' style='margin:10px 2px;'>
        <div class='text-left' th:text='${sku.name}'>name:</div>
        <div class='text-left' th:text='${sku.price}'>name:</div>
    </div>
</div>"                                             
data-html="true" th:text="${sku.name}"></div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer, I tested and worked. Please, try and let me know.

Comment: it is working perfectly, thank you @Guilherme

Comment: Good to hear that! Please, don't forget to accept the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

You have to use the `th:title` for processing the variables. The are basically two issues in your code:

1. You must encode your tags, e.g.:

   `< becomes &lt;`

   `> becomes &gt;`
2. You must put your HTML tags inside quotes concatenating with your variable outside the quotes, e.g.:

   `th:title="'&lt;div&gt;' + ${sku.name} + '&lt;/div&gt;'" data-html="true"`

Note that as much complex your HTML tags are, the more difficult will be handling all the encoding. I suggest you simplify your tags and increase the complexity step by step.

Answer (score 2):

As on today's date, I am using Thymeleaf 3.0.11 and Spring Boot 2.3.3. None of the answers worked for me.

I was looking for html's `title="something"` replacement in Thymeleaf.

Following did the trick for me:

```
<div th:if="not ${case.lockedby eq null}">
<span class="text-danger" th:attr="title=${case.lockedby}" ><i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i></span>
</div>
```

To answer original question (if I understood clearly) this is all we need:

```
th:attr="title=${sku.name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Guilherme for the repsonse.
However, I can't add html tag inside th:attr. it will work when I use

```
th:attr="data-title=${sku.name}"
```

but if I use

```
th:attr="data-title=<div>${sku.name}</div>"
```

then I got exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "data-title=< div >${sku.name}< /div >"
```